# python select specific elements from a list

Tags: python, list

Is there a "pythonic" way of getting only certain values from a list, similar to this perl code:

```
my ($one,$four,$ten) = line.split(/,/)[1,4,10]
```

Comment: Btw, that isn't valid Perl. Rather: `my (...) = (split /,/, $line)[1,4,10];`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think you are looking for `operator.itemgetter`:

```
import operator
line=','.join(map(str,range(11)))
print(line)
# 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
alist=line.split(',')
print(alist)
# ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
one,four,ten=operator.itemgetter(1,4,10)(alist)
print(one,four,ten)
# ('1', '4', '10')
```

Comment: Not really.  If you take out the demonstrative code it can look like this: one,four,ten=operator.itemgetter(1,4,10)(line.split(','))

Comment: You’re a lifesaver, thanks! If timeit is right, this should reduce the runtime of a codesnippet we examined today from 9 hours to a few seconds.

Comment: Unnecessary to use a library when it can be achieved with list comprehension, see @has2k1 answer.

Answer (score 43):

Using a list comprehension

```
line = '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'
lst = line.split(',')
one, four, ten = [lst[i] for i in [1,4,10]]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
lst = line.split(',')
one, four, ten = lst[1], lst[4], lst[10]
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question

Comment: @Idan: may be I have, am I not supposed to get 2nd, 5th and 11th elements of the new list?

Comment: @Idan K: There's no requirement that the "Pythonic" version be a single expression like the Perl version.

Comment: Although itemgetter might satisfy the OP's request in one line, I have to agree with Lennart here that this solution is most readable and easily understandable

Answer (score 5):

Try [operator.itemgetter](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) (available in python 2.4 or newer):

> Return a callable object that fetches item from its operand using the operand’s ____getitem____() method. If multiple items are specified, returns a tuple of lookup values.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> line = ','.join(map(str, range(11)))
>>> line
'0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10'
>>> a, b, c = itemgetter(1, 4, 10)(line.split(','))
>>> a, b, c
('1', '4', '10')
```

Condensed:

```
>>> # my ($one,$four,$ten) = line.split(/,/)[1,4,10]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> (one, four, ten) = itemgetter(1, 4, 10)(line.split(','))
```

Comment: You’re a lifesaver, thanks! If timeit is right, this should reduce the runtime of a codesnippet we examined today from 9 hours to a few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
index = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[i for j, i in enumerate(x) if index[j] == 1]
#[1, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
data = line.split(',')
one, four, ten = data[1], data[4], data[10]
```

You can also use itemgetter, but I prefer the code above, it's clearer, and clarity == good code.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you had a Numpy array instead of a list, you could do womething like:

```
from numpy import array

# Assuming line = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
line_array = array(line.split(","))

one, four, ten = line_array[[1,4,10]]
```

The trick here is that you can pass a list (or a Numpy array) as array indices.

**EDIT :** I first thought it would also work with tuples, but it's a bit more complicated. I suggest to stick with lists or arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
line = "0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
line_series = pd.Series(line.split(','))
one, four, ten = line_series[[1,4,10]]
```